# Expectancy of stationary 2-dimensional autoregression model

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, expected-value

Let us have the following AutoRegression process, expressed in term of lag operators:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1-0.4L & 0.1L \\ 0.1L & 1-0.4L \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_t \\ y_t \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 10 + e_{1t} \\ 1 + e_{2t} \end{pmatrix}$$

I have checked that $1-0.8L+0.15L^2$ has roots $\frac{10}{3}$ and $2$ so the process is stationary. I know how to find mean for a one-dimensional process, which is just applying "inverse operator" to the constant term. You just omit $L$s

I tried to do the same 
$$ \frac{1}{0.35} \begin{pmatrix} 0.6 & -0.1  \\  -0.1 & 0.6 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 10 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{10}{7} \\ \frac{40}{35} \end{pmatrix}$$

Is this method still legit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are considering a vector autoregressive (VAR) process. VAR($p$) is written as:

$$\mathbf{\pi}(L)\mathbf{Y}_t = \mathbf{c} +\epsilon_t$$

where $\mathbf{\pi}(L)=\mathbf{I}_n-\pi_1L-...-\pi_pL^p$, and VAR($p$) is said to be stable if $\det\left(\mathbf{\pi}(L)=\mathbf{I}_n-\pi_1z-...-\pi_pz^p\right)$ have modulus greater than one. If it is stationary then:
$$\mathbf{\mu} = (\mathbf{I}_n-\pi_1-...-\pi_p)^{-1}\mathbf{c}$$

So, for bivariate VAR($1$) model: $\mathbf{Y}_t=\pi\mathbf{Y}_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$
$$\begin{matrix} 
y_{1t} \\
y_{2t} 
\end{matrix} = \begin{matrix} 
\pi_{11} & \pi_{12} \\
\pi_{21} & \pi_{22} 
\end{matrix}\times\begin{matrix} 
y_{1t-1} \\
y_{2t-1} 
\end{matrix}+\begin{matrix} 
\epsilon_{1t} \\
\epsilon_{2t} 
\end{matrix}$$
Then $\det(\mathbf{I}_2-\pi z)=0$ becomes:
$$(1-\pi_{11})(1-\pi_22 z)-\pi_{12}\pi_{21}z^2=0$$
Notice if $\pi_{12}=\pi_{21}=0$ then it reduces to univariate stability condition. I will leave it here, as extensive material is available online on this matter.

**Reference Links**

1. https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/varModels.pdf
2. https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/11/11.2

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me some reference to start with?

Comment: See the links, hopefully they will be useful. I guess you could tweak the code of examples in the above links and solve your problem.